# How to convert a set into a vector in DolphinDB

Tags: dolphindb

I tried function 'array' but looks like it doesn't take a set as input. It doesn't work either if I create an empty vector first and then append the set to the vector. Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Please use function `keys` to convert a set to an array.

```
myset = set(1 3 5 7 9)
myset.keys()
```